# trying to update database using inputed values from textboxes PHP

Tags: php, mysql

what i am trying to do is to get the value inputed in the textbox then insert that value into the database

this code seems to be working but it only changes the value chosen to 0

```
   <?php

 $q1 = $_POST['q1'] ;
$q2 = $_POST['q2'] ;
$q3 = $_POST['q3'] ;
$q4 = $_POST['q4'] ;

$qe = $_POST['qe'] ;

$LT1 = $_POST['LT1'] ;
$LT2 = $_POST['LT2'] ; 

$THW = $_POST['THW'] ;
$TSW = $_POST['TSW'] ;

$Ct = $_POST['Ct'] ;
$Pj = $_POST['Pj'] ;
```

$insert = mysql_query("UPDATE grades SET HQ1 =  ' .  $q1 . '   WHERE ID='4011909'");

?>

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Duplicate of your own question: [Update database using values from texbox <PHP>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735069/update-database-using-values-from-texbox-php). If a question gets closed then **edit** it, **don't** *duplicate* it.

Comment: Should be: $insert = mysql_query("UPDATE grades SET HQ1 = "' . $q1 . '" WHERE ID='4011909'");

Comment: @Stefan — No, that's now a PHP syntax error instead of an SQL syntax error.

Comment: nothing happens if

mysql_query("UPDATE grades SET HQ1 = ".  $q1 ." WHERE ID='4011909'");

Comment: @Quentin - I don't think so...?  msql_query() accepts a string, and I supply a string.

Comment: @Stefan — No, you have a string literal, then an apostrophe, and that is a syntax error.

Comment: @Das Javilinar - That's not what I said you should change it to.

Comment: @Quentin:  I have (and I quote :) "UPDATE grades SET HQ1 = ' " . $q1 . " ' WHERE ID='4011909' ");

Comment: @Stefan — I copy/pasted it. You have `"` before the `'`.

Comment: It's the wrong solution anyway as it continues being vulnerable to SQL Injection and depends on a deprecated API.

Comment: @Quentin: I checked - you are right, I made a mistake.  Also agree about deprecated API.

Comment: @Quentin sori kind of new here still in highschool thats why im still a bit inexperienced

Answer (score 0):

remove the concatenation symbol in the query

```
$insert = mysql_query("UPDATE grades SET HQ1 = '$q1' WHERE ID='4011909'");
```

Comment: tried typing 25 but 0 comes out i removed the concatenation marks already